# React syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial to build a basic react app (first time using react) and am getting the following error when I try to run with nodemon:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The offending < is in the main.js file

```
var React = require('react');
var App = require('./components/App');

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

As I say, I'm new to react - is there any way round the use of < here? I've minified js as per the tutorial instructions.

Comment: Did you add this JS file as jsx to your HTML document?

Comment: This error sounds like the code isn't being converted from JSX to JS

Comment: Also, what version of React are you using? `0.14` and later should be using `ReactDOM.render`. PS. This does not relate to your problem, just extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Your React [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) code can live in a separate file. Lets name your file `app.js`

File content:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Then reference it from your HTML document:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
```

Click [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) to get more info

Comment: Thanks Ali, I'll have a look through those documents to see what I can get done with this. Much appreciated.